# object has no attribute 'driver'

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

---

Hello I am trying to build an automation infrastructure I built an ObjectRepository where commands are implemented in selenium where I use ObjectTest and pass the function to TestOne.
The error is:

```
TestOne :: test_one - AttributeError: 'ObjectTest' object has no attribute 'driver'
```

---

```
class ObjectRepository:

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

    def click1(self, element):
        return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(element).click()
```

```
class ObjectTest:

    search = (By.XPATH, "//a[contains(text(),'Gmail')]")

    def click_gmail(self):
        a = ObjectRepository(self.driver)
        a.click1(*ObjectTest.search)
```

```
class TestOne(Base.Base):

    def test_one(self):
        one = ObjectTest()
        one.click_gmail()
```

Comment: Can you share full stack trace?

Comment: https://github.com/liel00/AutomationInfrastructure

Answer (score 1):

From the code in the question I can't see that

1. driver defined and initialized in `class ObjectRepository` is passed into `class ObjectTest`.
2. there is an import such as

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

in `class ObjectRepository` so as Python will "understand" what `self.driver = driver` means

Comment: i import from selenium import webdriver
but Did not fix it

Comment: I suppose `class ObjectTest` should import the `class ObjectRepository` as well. Paragraph 1 in my answer

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
def __init__(self, driver=None):
    if driver is None:
        driver={}
    else:
        self.driver= driver
```